# Page rendering before Promise resolves in Node, Express, mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, promise

I have removed error handling code as it is working (for simplicicty).

I have a function `createOrder()` which creates a new record in my MongoDB collection:

```
createOrder = order => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Order.create({orderId: order});
    resolve();
});
```

`getOrders()` function that adds all current orders in the database to an array.

```
getOrders = _ => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Order.find({buyerId: curUser.userId}, (err, orders) => {
        orders.map(order => order.status != 'cancelled' ? curUserOrders.push(order) : null);
    });
    resolve();
});
```

An external javascript file to post an order:

```
postOrder = () => {
    window.location = `/new_order/order=${JSON.stringify(itemArray)}`;
}
```

and the node application that "gets" the request:

```
app.get("/new_order/order=:order", (req, res) => {
    createOrder(JSON.parse(req.params.order))
    .then(getOrders)
    .then(_ => res.render("userprofile", {user : curUser, orders: curUserOrders}));
});
```

when i post a new order the `postOrder()` function is triggered and `"userprofile"` is displayed but none of the orders are displayed until i refresh the page **again**. Im still learning how promises work so im guessing the problem lies there. Please help :).

Comment: Put the resolve() inside Order.create() & Order.find() . Both of these are asynchronous & your promise is getting resolved immediately.

Comment: Also don't forget to pass the data inside resolve() to be received after the promise is resolved.

Comment: thank you i understand now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises are used for asynchronous operations, but your example resoves the promise right away.

```
createOrder = order => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Order.create({orderId: order});
    resolve();
});
```

You would write the create function like:

```
createOrder(order).then(()=>{
   // The asynchronous operation is completed!
})
```

But in your case it would happen the following:

```
createOrder = order => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //Start the asynchronous operation ....
    Order.create({orderId: order});

    //... but you just resolve the operation right away.
    resolve();
});
```

A better example is probably the other function:

```
getOrders = _ => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Order.find({buyerId: curUser.userId}, (err, orders) => {
        orders.map(order => order.status != 'cancelled' ? curUserOrders.push(order) : null);
    });
    // You just resolve without waiting for the callback of find.
    resolve();
});
```

What you want:

```
getOrders = _ => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Order.find({buyerId: curUser.userId}, (err, orders) => {
        orders.map(order => order.status != 'cancelled' ? curUserOrders.push(order) : null);
        // Here we call resolve inside the callback and we wait for the find method and return the orders to the getOrders().then(orders => {}) call.
        resolve(orders);
    });

});
```

A Promise is what the name suggests, it provides you with a promise, that it will be fulfilled (resolved) at some point in the future. So you always want to wait with the resolve function until all operations are completed without errors.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have already answered in the comments . It's detailed now.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as callback like this

```js
createOrder = order => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Order.create({orderId: order}).then(()=>{resolve});
});
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!